# convert byte to short in Python

Tags: python, arrays, byte

I have written the following function to convert byte to short in Java. This is working fine. However, now I want to do the same thing in Python, but not able to understand how to convert it into Python code.

```
public static short byte_to_short(int myIndex, byte[] myByte){
    short sh = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       sh<<=8;
       sh |= (myByte[myIndex + i] & 0xff);
    }
    return sh;
}
```

Comment: Are you searching for [`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes)?

Comment: @OlvinRoght. Not really. Since int is 4 bytes, and short is 2 bytes.

Comment: In Java, you may find java.nio.ByteBuffer useful. Simply do ```ByteBuffer.wrap(myByte).getShort(myIndex)``` (while keeping in mind endianness ofc)

Comment: @TreeBig, there is no *short* in python, the only built-in integer [numeric type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) is [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). There is [`c_short`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_short) in `ctypes` but normally you won't use it unless some native API call required. If you want to convert just a 2 bytes, [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) two bytes from original.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) library:

```
import struct

# assuming myByte is your byte array:
len_count = len(myByte)/2

sh = struct.unpack('H'*len_count , myByte)
```